# calendar.gettimeinmillis vs system.currenttimemillis

Tags: java, android

What is the difference?

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);

List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST,cal.getTimeInMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`calendar.getTimeInMillis()` will return time set on particular calendar object in millisecond. Let's say total milliseconds spend from `midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC` to time set on calendar object.

While `System.currentTimeMillis()` will return current time on your device in millisecond. In other word, total milliseconds spend from `midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC` until now.

Comment: @TylerDurden welcome, you can accept the answer if it what you want to know.